# Is there a way to apply css to elements without adding a class to table elements?

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following...

```
td {
    padding: 8px;
}

 td a {
     display: block;
     padding: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

I'd like to apply the first css code to all `<td>` elements that do not have `<a>` and I'd like to apply the second one to only those that do have `<a>`.

I tried the following:

```
td:not(a) {
    padding: 8px;
}

td:not(td a) {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

How can I make this work without adding classes to the elements?

Comment: Not possible with CSS only. You will need to add class to distinguish cells.

Comment: I thought that was the case but was hoping that there was some way that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: No, CSS doesn't have "contains" (used to have this one, but it meant text content, not tags) or "has". So you will JS to set class on TD first.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JavaScript. Let's say you want any `td` with an `<a>` element within (I'll assume directly within for simplicity) to have a yellow background. Here's an example in jQuery:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>No a elements here</td>
    <td>I have an <a href="#">a</a> element.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td a').parent().css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

Pen at https://codepen.io/wahhabb/pen/QvxEjd